# Send xml to web service and get response

Tags: xml, visual-studio, web-services

I have an endpoint to a web service, I have a .wsdl file with the information in it, as well as a .xsd file. I have created a web reference application using the endpoint in VS. Now I want to send an xml file as a string and get some form of response from the service. HOW can I do this? I need a complete waalkthrough in terms of VS. Thanks for your time.

Comment: first google link for "web service visual studio" http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to send XML as a string? Surely this XML has some known structure that should be part of the service's contract, i.e. The WSDL.

Given the WSDL,Visual Studio will genarate a proxy for the service. You then call it's 
methods.

Does this help at all?

Comment: After some research I realise that I was mislead as to what was required, your absolutely right that the whole point of web services is not to send the xml as a string, what I need to do is get a response from the web service, I know I will have to make a client application and add a web reference to it which would be the web service end point, there are about 5 elements in the xml, account number etc, perhaps you could tell me the best method of calling the methods? Really appreciate your comment @H den Breejen. A walkthrough of how to do this in VS from you would be great.

Comment: You say you have created an endpoint using the wsdl and xsd. That means you should now have à proxy class in your project. Inspect it's methods and it's parameters. Calling it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @H den Breejen, ill give it a bash!